# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client at Server Response

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am trying to create a simple REST API with NodeJS and Express with the mongo database. I have stored all of my data in JSON files. The data is in the form of an array of objects.

I have paths like

```
fund-name/:portId`try {
      const { email, password } = req.body;
      const user = await Users.findOne({ email });
      if (!user)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "This email is not exists." });

      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (isMatch) {
        const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id, role: user.role }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
          expiresIn: "1h",
        });
        const { _id, firstName, lastName, email, role, fullName } = user;
        res.status(200).json({
          token,
          user: {
            _id,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            role,
            fullName,
          },
        });
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Password is incorrect." });
      }

      // console.log(user);
      res.json({ msg: "Login Successfully." });


    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: error.message });
    } let token = req.headers.authorization;
    
    const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    req.user = user;
    console.log(req.user);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem with :

```
let token = req.headers.authorization;
token = token.replace('Bearer ', '');
const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
req.user = user;
console.log(req.user);
```